# Twitter-like tweet box using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I really need your help. I have been googling around for how to make a tweet box like twitter's "What's happening" box for user to post new content using bootstrap 3 but so far I cannot find anything close.

[image]

Anyone have any idea or keyword that could help? Thank you very much!

Comment: bootstrap is not a hard requirement. If there is simple css solution please advice me as well. Thanks :-)

Comment: I think this is not easy but this seems to be common question, don't know why there isn't entry asking about this?

Comment: Use css :focus property to extend the length of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find a lot of plugins to do the same . But If you want do it your own follow the below steps  (this contain only basic functionality)

Define a span or div like below

```
  <div class="container">
  <div id="mockTextBox">
    What's Happening ?
  </div></br>
  <textarea id="originalTextBox" class="form-control">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Hide the textarea at first and show the span/div as textbox.

Then define the events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#originalTextBox').hide()
  $('#mockTextBox').click(function(){
    $('#mockTextBox').hide()
    $('#originalTextBox').show()
  })
})
```

Apply CSS accordingly and you got what you want.

```
#mockTextBox
{
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#originalTextBox
{
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  resize:none;
}
```

Check this sample http://codepen.io/Midhun052/pen/mVByzK

I have add the bootstrap class to text area in the codepen above for that nice look.

**Just updated**

A few more CSS and Images

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#originalTextBox').hide()
  $('#mockTextBox').click(function() {
    $('#mockTextBox').hide()
    $('#originalTextBox').show()
  })
})
```

```css
#mockTextBox
{
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #337ab7;
  
}

#txt
{
 border:1px solid; 
 display:inline;
  height:20px;
  
}

#originalTextBox
{
    width: 310px;
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #337ab7;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    margin: 10px;
}

#originalTextBox textarea
{
 
  resize:none;
  margin:5px;
  width:300px;
}

.class2
{
     float: right;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.imgF1
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  margin:5px
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">  
  <div id="mockTextBox">   
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/46/46"/>
    <div id="txt">What's Happening ?</div>
    <img class="class2" src="http://lorempixel.com/16/16"/>
  </div>
  <div id="originalTextBox">
  <textarea  class="form-control">
  </textarea>
    <img class="imgF1" src="http://lorempixel.com/46/46">Post your photo</img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Midhun. It looks nice. But could we do it as twitter with such beautiful style? No resize icon at the corner. It seems they do not use textarea.

Comment: We can do that If needed , Let me know . I am busy now . Will do later end of the day

Comment: @longbkit , we need to apply style to textarea style resize:none . I have updated the codepen

Comment: @longbkit just improved it a little more

Comment: Looks pretty nice. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple jQuery application.
Check [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) out. 
Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/HrnHb/).

Then all you gotta do is initiate the jQuery.
Such as:

```
$('textarea').autogrow({onInitialize: true});
```

Check fiddle for more info.
Cheers!

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Use CSS to style your textarea, no need for javascrcipt styling here. Prepare your style in CSS under a specific class and when you need to, you can add your element this class and its propeties. This is much cleaner solution. Use focus and blur events to get textarea element. Here is example.

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtArea">

<textarea>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#txtArea').on("focus", function(event) {

        if(!$('#txtArea').hasClass('customTextAreaClass')){

        $('#txtArea').addClass('customTextAreaClass');

    }
});

$('#txtArea').on("blur", function(event) {

    if($('#txtArea').hasClass('customTextAreaClass')){

        $('#txtArea').removeClass('customTextAreaClass');

    }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.customTextAreaClass{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 565px;
    color: #000;
    height: 120px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    font-family: "Tahoma", Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: groove 1px #e5eaf1;
    position: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ishan Patel. It looks pretty close to twitter but I would like the textarea to expand right when user click on it as in twitter. Also in twitter when I view the html they are not using textarea at all. That's why they have a beautiful input display that have no resize icon at the corner like a textarea. Do you have any idea?

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I've found a much cleaner way using only css. Will share with you later.